# JEditorPane html auto formatting

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

The HTMLEditorKit in the JEditorPane format the HTML code with its own indentation and brokes "too long" lines.

I've tried with the simplest code:

```
JEditorPane jtpMain = new JEditorPane();
HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)(htmlKit.createDefaultDocument());
htmlDoc.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
jtpMain.setEditorKit(htmlKit);
String text = "<p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>";
jtpMain.setText(text);
System.out.println(jtpMain.getText());
```

The result is:

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
      bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
      bla bla bla bla bla bla
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to avoid this, specifically I need to keep the line as in the original source, without interruptions. 
The EditorKit provides a way to change this? Maybe parametrizing the output (indentation spaces, character per line,...)?

Comment: *"I need to keep the line as in the original source"* Why?

Comment: You can replace all the space characters by the &nbsp;